# merge feature branch to main error: You are attempting to modify a pull request based on out-of-date information

Tags: git, bitbucket

Please assist me.

I want to merge my feature branch to develop branch after my pull request was approved.

I then used PowerShell to run and ran the merge command like this:

I first checked out to the develop branch using: git checkout develop.
then I ran the git merge command: git merge feature-calendar-alignment.
this is the output I received:

```
Updating 8321f..113b88c
Fast-forward
.../calendar.component.html  | 176 +++++++++------------
.../calendar.component.less  |   3 +
2 files changed, 80 insertions(+), 99 deletions(-)
```

When I run the git log my changes are confirmed:
commit 113b88c60c1209d3ca6c68c1237da (HEAD -> develop, origin/feature-calendar-alignment,
enter feature-calendar-alignment)
Author: Sivuyile sivuyile@xxx.co.za
Date:   Mon Aug 2 15:57:43 2021 +0200

My issue is when I check commit on the develop branch using the web interface I do not see my commit there?

When log on the develop web application, I do not see my changes.
I also tried using the merge button on my pull request but received a message an error message(You are attempting to modify a pull request based on out-of-date information.).

Can you please help me merge my feature branch to develop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1.) Everything you do on your machine is only on your machine. (You have to push your new commits to the server to see them there.) 2.) You probably shouldn't, or can't, push your commit on `develop` to the server; you should complete the PR using the web interface, like you tried. 3.) Maybe you just need to refresh the page before completing the PR in the web interface?

Comment: Page reload help me with the "You are attempting to modify a pull request based on out-of-date information" message

Answer (score 6):

It got resolved after reloading the pull-request page.

Answer (score 0):

hi  I also got this same error because of  one more merge is going on so i waited for some time and tried the issue got resolved